# TextView setGravity() doesn't work in java

Tags: java, android, android-layout, bug-tracking, gravity

I'm stuck on a problem and I don't know, what causes it.
I have a very simple Layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/my_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="NOTE_THIS"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="22dp"
    android:text="TestText"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

which is included inside another layout. If I change the gravity inside the xml I see same Result in Layout-Editor and on my phone. If I wanna apply the Gravity programatically like with `myTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER)` it doesn't Change anything. And I cannot set LayoutGravity in Java on a TextView

I'll tried for debug purposes to include them three times each with another gravity which does work even. So I assume everything is alright with my Layout and there has to be a Bug or something else I miss. 
Can someone give me a hint what I also can try, or what causes this problem?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Set your TextView's width as `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` then you can set it programmatically using `myTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER)`

Comment: how can I get The intrinsicWidth of the TextView after giving it "fill_parent", because getWidth gives me the width of parent LienearLayout

Comment: why do you need that for setting gravity only?

Comment: because its not setting gravity only, but rezising the text, which works if I get the correct width of it

Comment: "rezising the text" do you mean it changes the text size too? it shouldn't be possible

Answer (score 7):

You need to set the gravity of the LayoutParams object instead of the View itself:

```
TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use LinearLayout as parent, then layout_gravity comes in picture which align control but not content inside the control so,
Instead using `android:layout_gravity` use `android:gravity`.

Comment: Ah sorry it was my fault... I want to set LayoutGravity because Gravity does nothing... updated my Question